# Nodejs add variable into imported html string

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Hello i'm currently having trouble trying to insert a variable into a long html string which i got from readFileSync, i'm trying to insert a token at the end of an href url in the html.

My test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
  style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Actionable emails e.g. reset password</title>


  <style type="text/css">
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    body {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
      width: 100% !important;
      height: 100%;
      line-height: 1.6em;
    }

    body {
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
      body {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }

      h1 {
        font-weight: 800 !important;
        margin: 20px 0 5px !important;
      }

      h2 {
        font-weight: 800 !important;
        margin: 20px 0 5px !important;
      }

      h3 {
        font-weight: 800 !important;
        margin: 20px 0 5px !important;
      }

      h4 {
        font-weight: 800 !important;
        margin: 20px 0 5px !important;
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 22px !important;
      }

      h2 {
        font-size: 18px !important;
      }

      h3 {
        font-size: 16px !important;
      }

      .container {
        padding: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important;
      }

      .content {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }

      .content-wrap {
        padding: 10px !important;
      }

      .invoice {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage"
  style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; width: 100% !important; height: 100%; line-height: 1.6em; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0;"
  bgcolor="#f6f6f6">

  <table class="body-wrap"
    style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; width: 100%; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0;"
    bgcolor="#f6f6f6">
    <tr
      style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
      <td
        style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0;"
        valign="top"></td>
      <td class="container" width="600"
        style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; display: block !important; max-width: 600px !important; clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto;"
        valign="top">
        <div class="content"
          style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; max-width: 600px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px;">
          <table class="main" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" itemprop="action" itemscope
            itemtype="http://schema.org/ConfirmAction"
            style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 3px; background-color: #fff; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;"
            bgcolor="#fff">
            <tr
              style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
              <td class="content-wrap"
                style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 20px;"
                valign="top">
                <meta itemprop="name" content="Confirm Email"
                  style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;" />
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                  style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
                  <tr
                    style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
                    <td class="content-block"
                      style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;"
                      valign="top">
                      Please confirm your email address by clicking the link below.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr
                    style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
                    <td class="content-block"
                      style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;"
                      valign="top">
                      We may need to send you critical information about our service and it is important that we have an
                      accurate email address.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr
                    style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
                    <td class="content-block" itemprop="handler" itemscope
                      itemtype="http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler"
                      style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;"
                      valign="top">
                      <a href="https://91bf2bdc.ngrok.io/verify/?{token}` class=" btn-primary" itemprop="url"
                        style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; line-height: 2em; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; border-radius: 5px; text-transform: capitalize; background-color: #348eda; margin: 0; border-color: #348eda; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px 20px;">Confirm
                        email address</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr
                    style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
                    <td class="content-block"
                      style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;"
                      valign="top">
                      &mdash; BB
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <div class="footer"
            style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; width: 100%; clear: both; color: #999; margin: 0; padding: 20px;">
            <table width="100%"
              style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
              <tr
                style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
                <td class="aligncenter content-block"
                  style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 12px; vertical-align: top; color: #999; text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;"
                  align="center" valign="top">Follow <a href="http://twitter.com/mail_gun"
                    style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 12px; color: #999; text-decoration: underline; margin: 0;">@Mail_Gun</a>
                  on Twitter.</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td
        style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0;"
        valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

In the html i place the href in like so :

```
href="https://91bf2bdc.ngrok.io/verify/?{token}`
```

My import_html.js file:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const emailtemplate = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'/test.html'), 'utf8');

const token = "eg2h4t41vn1j21h12gdd1212";

const emailString = eval('`'+emailtemplate+'`');


console.log(emailString);
```

I would like the place the token at the end of the url when i print the html string out it should contain this:

```
href="https://91bf2bdc.ngrok.io/verify/eg2h4t41vn1j21h12gdd1212"
```

But when i try to run with node it return the following error:

```
node import_html.js                                                    
at 09:31:13 undefined:138 <a href="https://91bf2bdc.ngrok.io/verify/?{token}` class=" btn-primary" itemprop="url"

^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token class
```

Any help would be appreciate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be more elegant to use replace instead of eval?

```js
const emailtemplate = '<...previous htmlcode...><a href="https://91bf2bdc.ngrok.io/verify/?{token}<...end of htmlcode...>';

const token = "eg2h4t41vn1j21h12gdd1212";

const emailString = emailtemplate.replace(/\?{token}/,token);

console.log(emailString);
```

Comment: thank you for the regex suggestion :) it worked now

Answer (score 0):

You're template string started with a double quote instead of a backtick. That's why it's showing class in the error as the string is currently being closed off after the `=`

Your original line:

```
href="https://91bf2bdc.ngrok.io/verify/?{token}`
```

Changing it to this should fix it:

```
href=`https://91bf2bdc.ngrok.io/verify/?{token}`
```

Comment: That shouldn't matter because it's being surrounded with \`backticks\` and eval'd. I think the problem with the source is probably that template strings use `${}` and not `?{}`. It would still probably be better to follow @Vincent 's suggestion and use replace instead of eval.